# Exporting map to KML using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, kml

I've been trying to convert a map from ArcMap to KML without exit. The issue is that I want to export the complete map, not only the layers in the data frame but also legend, symbols, grid ticks and so on but the Map to KML tool does not have an option (as far as I know) to keep them.

I must do it in ArcMap so does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: No tool in ArcGIS will do this. Legends, grids etc are aspatial and the symbology definitions allowed in KML/KMZ are substantially more restrictive than offered by ArcGIS. The only potential I can see is using Google as a background in an Esri ArcGIS online map but your result will not be KML/KMZ, just online.

Comment: KML is not a map format.  Think of it more as a layer(s) format.

Answer (score 2):

Not straightway, however a workaround can be like this.

In ArcMap, you could export the Layout View that contains legend, grid etc to a PDF with "Export Map GeoReference Information" option.

[image]

Then, export the [GeoPDF to a GeoTIFF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/pdf-to-tiff.htm).

```
import arcpy
#Define variables
inPDF = r'C:\Project\export.pdf'
outTIFF = r'C:\Project\export.tif'

#Export PDF to GeoTIFF
arcpy.PDFToTIFF_conversion(inPDF, outTIFF)
```

This GeoTiFF can be added into Google Earth as an Image Overlay.

Comment: Thank's a lot Thiru this was what I was looking for. It works even better for me as an Image Overlay.

Comment: You are welcome @LE_Geomatica. Glad, I could help.